# como enviar push de um celular para o outro, ionic 3-4

Tags: push-notification, ionic4

Já fiz um app simples de push notification, mandando a notificação para o app, usando o OneSignal e Firebase,

é possível fazer um app, que mande a notificação, de um celular para o outro ? usando o OneSignal ou Firebase, mas que não precise mandar a mensagem pelo site das ferramentas mencionadas acima,

Exemplo um aplicativo de mensagens, eu mando o push de um celular android, o outro dispositivo recebe o push, e vice versa...

Alguém me ajuda ?